# Using array_push to append to end of a desired line (PHP)

Tags: php, file

So I'm trying to append a string at the end of a row. The row and the string is inputted by the user.

```
//irrelevant...
$row = $_POST["whichRow"];
$Comment = $_POST["stringValue"];

$lines = array();
$arrayWithComment = array(";", "$actualComment");
$lineCount = 0;

foreach(file('/var/www/html/bkbpNew/tickets.csv') as $line){    

if ($lineCount == $row){
        array_push($lines, $line, $arrayWithComment[0], $arrayWithComment[1]);}
    else{
        array_push($lines, $line);}

    $lineCount++;
}

file_put_contents('/var/www/html/bkbpNew/tickets.csv', $lines);
```

And that sort of works, but not in the way that I want it to. Here is the edited file before/after & the desired state:

---

*(Input values for this example are comment = "test" and row = 2)*

#### Desired result of edited file:

```
1;example;example;example;example;example;example
2;example;example;example;example;example;example;test
3;example;example;example;example;example;example
```

#### Edited file BEFORE the above code is executed:

```
1;example;example;example;example;example;example
2;example;example;example;example;example;example
3;example;example;example;example;example;example
```

#### Edited file AFTER the above code is executed:

```
1;example;example;example;example;example;example
2;example;example;example;example;example;example
;test3;example;example;example;example;example;example
```

it automatically goes into the next line ([Desired result](http://postimg.org/image/xnlhg7rdt/)) but I don't want it to. How do I go about this? Cheers!

Comment: *it automatically goes into the next line (Desired result) but I don't want it to*... So you don't ***desire*** your ***desired result***?

Comment: @Hanky Panky on the desired result I show that I want that to be in the previous line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use `file()`, newline characters are included at the end of the line, so when you're adding your new comment to the end of the line you're adding it **after** the new line character

I'm not a big fan of your approach to this, but as a quick and dirty solution use the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag for file(), and then manually re-add the newline characters for each line in your loop

Comment: How do I add them manually? `array_push($lines, $line, '\n');` the backslash n doesn't seem to work. Edit: had to use " instead of ' and it worked. How would you approach this?

Comment: Well personally, I wouldn't use a file anyway, I'd use a database

Comment: Because with this file approach, you'll hit problems if more than one person tries to comment on anything at the same time

Comment: I do use a database, but I also need a file where I can keep the history, because I will be deleting entries from the DB but I want to have every record in a text file.

Comment: Surely you can export from the database before doing your deletions if you want to keep a file archive record

Comment: in what format does it export it? The DB is running on a RPi